# What does ‘running out of breath’ mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I know **"out of breath"** means *having difficulty breathing after exercise*

What does ‘**running**’ in the following sentence mean? Does it mean ‘*becoming*’?

> George is trying really hard but he’s **running out of breath**.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The phrase [**to run out of something**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/run-out#run-out__1) is an idiomatic expression in English which means to use all of something and not have any left. Have you ever heard someone say *"I'm running out of milk"*? What they're saying is that they have used up almost all of their milk and there is almost none left. Maybe, there is still a little bit left, but for all intents and purposes, all their milk is pretty much gone. Transferring that idea over to your example, it means that even though George was trying really hard, he could not do any more whatever he was doing because he had used up almost all of his energy/breath.

Comment: As a footnote, this could mean something different with a comma: _George is trying really hard but he's running, out of breath_.

Comment: @J.R. Even without the comma, it could mean that.

Comment: Nitpick: "*it means that George could not **run** any more because...*" Nowhere do I see any indication that George is engaged in the activity of "*running*". He could be performing any activity physical, such as climbing, bicycling, jumping, dancing, etc. I point this out because the "*running*" in "*running out of breath*" has no relation to the activity of *running* specifically.

Comment: @DavidRicherby It *could* — if it weren’t for the idiom. Put differently, nobody would guess that you intended the meaning “running while out of breath” if you wrote “running out of breath” without the comma.

Comment: @KonradRudolph “Run out of X” is an idiom but so is “out of breath”. However, I have never heard “run out of breath” as an idiom so I dispute your claim that everybody would parse it as “running out of X, where X=breath”.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Idiom or not, “run(ning) out of breath” is a fairly common phrase. I’m pretty sure that it’s *never* used to mean “running while out of breath”. And if not never, then it’s below 1% of the total usage.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I'd agree that it's less common in the examples Waylan cites.  However in the case of anything which requires the ability to hold your breath or manage sustained release of breath - particular examples would be swimming underwater, singing or playing a wind instrument - this is *exactly* the phrase which would be used.

Comment: To borrow from the answer, it's an idiomatic usage. "Running out of milk" is never understood to mean "running, out of milk", or that the subject is literally "running". So the last sentence of the answer does not fit. Instead, it means "very short of <object>". George is short of breath; the subject in this answer is short of milk.

Comment: The sentence suggests that the subject is doing something energetic. I suspect Michael inadvertently conflated that with running because that's the word being discussed.

Comment: @Barmar Right, I was imagining a guy running a marathon. That's the first thing that came to mind and stuck there.

Comment: George is blowing bubbles unless I am very much mistaken. Not that it strictly matters what George is doing.